# Removing background from GIF image

Tags: library, javascript, gif

Is it possible to remove the black background from a GIF image using JavaScript? Is there any library available to do this?

I have checked the MarvinJ Library, but it seems it will only remove the background for JPEG/PNG images.

I am looking for a library which will take all the frames in a GIF image and remove the black background from it.